# Exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed`, when running code from Fat-JAR/Uber-JAR

Tags: java, maven, imagej, uberjar, fatjar

I have an issue with my software, when building and running it as an FatJAR/UberJar built with Maven. In this case I get this error:

```
Uncaught error fetching image:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:686)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipFile.java:366)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:452)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:164)
    at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(URLImageSource.java:127)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:263)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:205)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:169)
```

However, the software works correctly, when launched directly from IntelliJ.

I have created a minimal example to reproduce the error here:

https://github.com/michaelmell/bugfix_003-ImageJFunctions_show-call-fails-in-UberJar

The issue somehow has to do with this call (please see the Git repo for full code):

```
ImageJFunctions.show(input);
```

I suspect that I need to adjust the shading in `pom.xml`, but I am too unfamiliar with the configuration.
Please see the `pom.xml` and `deploy.sh` for details on how the JAR is built and the shading is done.

I have also stepped into the JAR using IntelliJ and set a break point in the dependency `URLImageSource::getDecoder` to check the URL that fails. It is:

```
/PATH/TO/THE/GIT/REPOSITORY/target/ImageJFunctions_show__failure_minimal_example-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/icons/imagej-256.png
```

which exists in the JAR the file: `icons/imagej-256.png`. Note that this is an icon, that is part of the imagej dependencies (not one that I introduce).

I don't really know what to try next and would welcome any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

`imagej-legacy` version `10.37.4` should fix this issue, which will be available soon via `pom-scijava 29.0.0` ([see here](https://forum.image.sc/t/error-using-imagejfunctions-show-from-uberjar-but-works-from-within-intellij/33185/10?u=michaelmell))

I tested `pom-scijava 29.0.0-beta-2` and confirmed that it fixes this issue.